# How do I write a new ListChangeListener<Item>() with lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, listener, java-8, changelistener

How do I write a new ListChangeListener() with lambda in java8?

```
listItems.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(
        javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Item> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

This is what I tried:

```
listItems.addListener(c->{});
```

But eclipse states:

> The method addListener(ListChangeListener) is ambiguous for the 
>   type ObservableList.

The List is declared as:

```
ObservableList<Item> listItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since `ObservableList` inherits `addListener(InvalidationListener)` from the `Observable` interface, the compiler is unable to determine which version to call. Specifying the type of the lambda through a cast should fix this.

```
listItems.addListener((ListChangeListener)(c -> {/* ... */}));
```

You can also explicitly specify the type of `c`:

```
listItems.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Item> c) -> {/* ... */});
```

Comment: `searchResultListItems.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Contact> c) ->{});`
did the trick thx for the hint

Comment: Cannot do the above option with ChangeListener. Using PropertyListeners... "Lambda expression`s signiture do not match the signature of the functional interface method changed(ObservableValue, Object, Object)". - When trying to: property.addListener((ChangeListener) e -> ({/* ... */}));

Answer (score 0):

This code works without having to specify the types.

```
listView.focusedProperty ().addListener ( (arg, oldVal, newVal) -> System.out
        .printf ("ListView %s focus%n", (newVal ? "in" : "out of")));
```

Comment: Your solution works for ListViews, but the question was about ObservableLists, which do not have a focusedProperty.